# Is there a way to know when question ban will be temporarily lifted?

Tags: support, post-ban

On my Stack Overflow account, I am currently banned from asking questions. I have, over time, asked a series of questions that were poorly worded and/or did not contribute to the site as a whole. On the FAQ, I saw that every six months you are allowed to ask a single question in order to attempt to lift the ban by positively contributing to the site. In the meantime, however, I have no idea how much longer I have to go until the ban lifts. Does anyone know if there is a way to find out how much time I have left until I can ask questions again?

I have read this page but it doesn't answer my question: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

(I am aware that the only way to lift the ban until the six months is up is to edit old questions. I am, in fact, in the process of editing them now in order to make them more relevant to other users. I was just curious if there is a way to know how long I have until the six months is up.)

Comment: Oh, by the way, doesn't actually look like you're banned any more right now. Some of your efforts must have borne fruit.

Comment: Yeah it happened just as I posted this. This is still good info to know for the future, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to look at the date of your last question, as that's generally when the ban starts.

In your case, that was [May 4th](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4665624/darien-springer?tab=questions&sort=newest). So, it may not be exact, but it's likely that your 6 month ban will be lifted for that one question about 182 days later... or something around November 4th.

That's not too much longer from now. Hopefully some of your edits or new questions will attract some upvotes so that you can keep out of the ban in the future.

Comment: I honestly don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you. And yeah, I am working to lift the ban. I am going to be much more careful about asking questions in the future.

Comment: Sure :D Consider trying out the Ask a Question Wizard (Prototype). It's still in testing but we're trying to help users do a better job of getting the right content into questions before they get downvoted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype?s=1|97.3317

Comment: Oh cool. I will be sure to check that out.

Answer (score 3):

Find out when you last asked a question, then add 6 months. According to the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans):

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one **6 months after your last question**.